Given a quadratic bézier curve, how can I know if P1 is within $\vec{V_1}\bot\overrightarrow{PT\to P2}$ and $\vec{V_2}\bot\overrightarrow{PT\to P0}$
In this case, t = 0.5 so PT is the middle of the curve
From what I understand, there are 2 possible solutions to this problem:

Finding the angle $\alpha$ between $\overrightarrow{P1\to P0}$ and $\overrightarrow{P0\to PT}$ ($\alpha \gt 90°$)
Projecting $\vec{V}_{P0\to P1}$ into $\vec{V}_{P0\to PT}$ and finding where the point Q is along the segment (Q $\lt$ $\mathbb0$)

This would then also have to be done for the other half segment of the curve.
Is either of these solutions acceptable or is there another, more straightforward way of solving this?
Sketch for visualizing the question
Visual representation of the problem

It's a convex combination (i.e. $t$*first + $(1-t)$*second) where $t\in(0,1)$, so $P_1$ is certainly "within" those two objects you mentioned in that sense.

@Snared I'm not sure I follow, would you be able to expand on that a little bit?

The definition of a quadratic bezier curve through $P$ and $Q$ is $tP+(1-t)Q$ for $t \in (0,1)$, just like I said, which proves it.

Perhaps you need to brush up on what it means for a function to be convex?

How are vectors $V_1$ and $V_2$ related to the Bézier curve?

@bubba They are perpendicular to the segment described by tracing a straight line from PT (middle of the curve) to their respective ends, as you can see here

@Snared That is not a solution, as you can see in this case, P1 lies outside the defined perpendicular bounds

I don’t understand the meaning of “within”, here. Or (more likely) I don’t understand the expression after the word “within”. What does the $\perp$ symbol mean, here?

You seem to be asking whether $P_1$ lies in some region. What region?

@bubba I don't mean to be a jerk but... seriously?
I appreciate the interest but it doesn't seem like you even read the description/replies
